# Find the database host name in plesk panel

Tags: plesk-onyx, database-server

I've created a database and database user in Plesk panel. I want to use the new database in another server, for this I need database host. Help me to find the database host in Plesk panel. (Note: it is an amazon server. I created a new instance and installed the Plesk panel for managing site files and databases)

I tried to find the database host by checking the database servers list ('Tools && settings' -> 'database servers'), but here host name is mentioned as localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If your database server is marked as 'localhost' that means that you have to use your Plesk server hostname as database hostname. You can find it in Tools&Settings > Server Settings > Full hostname